# Iterator-producing function in Nim: works when assigning the iterator, stuck when calling it directly

Tags: while-loop, iterator, nim-lang

I tried to make a procedure that creates an iterator, as follows:

```nim
proc makeCDFrom(start: int): iterator(): int =
  result = iterator(): int =
    var
      i: int = start
    while i >= 0:
      echo "i:", i
      yield(i)
      dec(i)

let cdFrom6 = makeCDFrom(6)
for j in cdFrom6():
  echo "j:", j
```

This appears to work as expected:

```
i:6
j:6
i:5
j:5
i:4
j:4
i:3
j:3
i:2
j:2
i:1
j:1
i:0
j:0
```

However, initially, I had tried with this slight variation:

```nim
proc makeCDFrom(start: int): iterator(): int =
  result = iterator(): int =
    var
      i: int = start
    while i >= 0:
      echo "i:", i
      yield(i)
      dec(i)

# Note the direct call:
for j in makeCDFrom(6)():
  echo "j:", j
```

When I try to run the above on https://play.nim-lang.org/, it appears to be stuck. Nothing gets displayed.

Why this difference?

Answer (score 3):

Why?

Because there's a bug.

What can you do about it?

Report the bug to github.com/nim-lang/Nim

And in the meantime use either

```
let myClosureIter = makeCDFrom(6)
```

or define your iterator without the factory:

```
iterator makeCDFrom(start: int): int =
    var
      i: int = start
    while i >= 0:
      echo "i:", i
      yield(i)
      dec(i)

# Note the direct call:
for j in makeCDFrom(6):
  echo "j:", j
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect a bug. For a beginner, strange behaviours usually have non-bug explanations. I reported here: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/15339

Comment: @bli It is probably the case that iterator factories can't be used in that way, so that shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

With a slight change:

```
proc makeCDFrom(start: int): iterator(): int =
  echo "called again"
  result = iterator(): int =
    var
      i: int = start
    while i >= 0:
      echo "i:", i
      yield(i)
      dec(i)
```

And running locally, it's in an infinite loop:

```
called again
i:6
called again
j:6
called again
i:6
called again
j:6
called again
i:6
...
```

Comment: Interesting. So this seems to imply that the `for <variables> in <something>` syntax executes the whole `<something>` at each step of the loop to get the `<variables>`. That said, I don't understand why there are 2 executions of `echo "called again"` per "cycle" (as the alternance of `i:6` and `j:6` suggests) instead of 1.