# how to iterate with two iterators

Tags: loops, iterator, nim-lang

I would like to use `nimbioseq` and iterate two files with the same number of sequences (using the `readSeq()`iterator), as:

```py
for seq1, seq2 in readSeq(file1), readSeq(file2):
  echo seq1.id, "\t", seq2.id
```

For this scenario I suppose I need some sort of "zipping" operator, which I couldn't understand how to use [ found this: https://hookrace.net/nim-iterutils/iterutils.html#zip.i,,Iterable[S] ].

or alternatively understand how to get a single "iteration" outside a for loop (if possible):

```py
for seq1 in readSeq(file1):
  let seq2 = readSeq(file2);
  echo seq1.id, "\t", seq2.id
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: I really want to thank you all for the fantastic answers. I did some tests but need to finish and will provide feedback asap.

Answer (score 2):

`toClosure` from iterutils is limited, but you can:

```py
import iterutils

template initClosure(id,iter:untyped) =
  let id = iterator():auto{.closure.} =
    for x in iter:
      yield x

initClosure(f1,readSeq(file1))
#creates a new closure iterator, 'f1'

initClosure(f2,readSeq(file2))
#creates a new closure iterator, 'f2'

for seq1,seq2 in zip(f1,f2):
  echo seq1.id,"\t",seq2.id
```

Edit: thanks to @pietropeter for pointing out the bug, here's their example rewritten using this template:

```py
import iterutils
template initClosure(id:untyped,iter:untyped) =
  let id = iterator():auto {.closure.} =
    for x in iter:
      yield x

iterator letters: auto =
  for c in 'a' .. 'z':
    yield c

# Now requires a parameter
iterator numbers(s: int): int =
  var n = s
  while true:
    yield n
    inc n

initClosure(cletter,letters())
initClosure(numbers8,numbers(8))

for (c, n) in zip(cletter, numbers8):
  echo c, n
```

Comment: I like the template approach and I was trying to apply it to the extended version but it fails: https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2z4b what am I doing wrong?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, i had id and iter both quoted still from my macro solution so my bad. the only change to your code is adding parens after letters.

Comment: Perfect! For me now this is the best answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use [this iterators code from Manual](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#iterators-and-the-for-statement-first-class-iterators), and insert your problem in it. I'm sure it has room for improvement:

```
type
  Task = iterator (r: var int)

iterator f1(r: var int){.closure.} =
  for n in [1, 3, 5]:
    r = n
    yield

iterator f2(r: var int){.closure.} =
  for n in [2, 4, 6]:
    r = n
    yield

proc runTasks(t: varargs[Task]) =
  var ticker = 0
  var r: int

  while true:
    var x = t[ticker mod t.len]
    x(r)
    echo r
    if finished(x): break
    inc ticker

runTasks(f1, f2)
```

You'll see in the output 1,2,3,4,5,6,6 (`finished` is prone to error, as stated in the manual, and returns the last item twice). You have to update the code, replacing `r: var int` with whatever type returns `readSeq(file)` (`r: var Record`, I think), and replace the iterators `for n in [1, 2, 3]` with `for s in readSeq(file)`.

Answer (score 1):

If the type of behaviour you want is that of `zip`, the one from iterutils seems to work fine. The only caveat is that it requires closure iterators (see [manual](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#iterators-and-the-for-statement-first-class-iterators) for the difference between inline and closure iterators). Example (https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2yXV):

```py
import iterutils

iterator letters: char {.closure.} =
  for c in 'a' .. 'z':
    yield c

iterator numbers: int {.closure.}=
  var n = 1
  while true:
    yield n
    inc n

for (c, n) in zip(letters, numbers):
  echo c, n
```

I see that [readseq](https://github.com/jhbadger/nimbioseq/blob/master/src/nimbioseq.nim#L234) in nimbioseq is not closure but probably something like this could work (**edit**: its should not, see below):

```py
iterator closureReadSeqs(filename: string): Record {.closure.} =
  for rec in readSeqs(filename):
    yield rec
```

### Edit

For the case of iterator with a parameter in the comments, the fix is to have a proc that returns an iterator (which will be a closure iterator by default in this case). Updated example (https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2z0e):

```py
import iterutils

iterator letters: char {.closure.} =
  for c in 'a' .. 'z':
    yield c

# Now requires a parameter
proc numbers(s: int): iterator(): int =
  return iterator(): int =
    var n = s
    while true:
      yield n
      inc n

let numbers8 = numbers(8)
for (c, n) in zip(letters, numbers8):
  echo c, n
```

Now my best guess on how to make this work for `nimbioseq` is:

```py
proc closureReadSeqs(filename: string): iterator(): Record =
  return iterator(): Record =
    for rec in readSeqs(filename):
      yield rec
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help. What I don't get at the moment is how to use `zip` with closures requiring a parameter. I tried with your closureReadSeqs but probaly my error is in how i use zip. I tried extending your example: https://gist.github.com/telatin/3e37d356937b1b2155b50b546ebb8982

Comment: You are right, the approach proposed would not work with iterators requiring a parameter. iterator semantics is kind of tricky (see e.g. for another example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63884552/iterator-producing-function-in-nim-works-when-assigning-the-iterator-stuck-whe/63906287#63906287). I updated my answer and the extended example now works (I used the approach mentioned here: https://nim-by-example.github.io/for_iterators/). Let me know if this helps also for nimbioseq.

Comment: also, since iterators and procs in nim have different namespaces (a somewhat deprecated feature, but probably here to stay for a while: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/8901), you should be able to name the above proc readSeqs and it should work fine.

Comment: Hi @Andrea T. I approved the edit to python syntax highlighting since it is currently the best option to have some syntax highlighting with Nim. Still I am hoping that soon we will have native syntax highlighting. They recently changed the highlighting engine from prettify to highlight.js, which does support Nim. As far as I understand they are still keeping the same scope of languages of prettify in this first phase of the migration, but I expect that Nim will be supported soon enough. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109